# Insert a user by default in MongoDB in Nest JS (Only when the app starts)

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

I am changing the project from expressjs to nestjs.

In express, I added an admin user to the database by default in app.ts.

like this:

```
public async addDefaultAdmin() {
    UserModel.find({ role: Roles.admin }).then(async (superAdmin) => {
      if (superAdmin.length === 0) {
        try {
          const newUser = new UserModel({...});
          await this.hashPassWord(newUser);
          await newUser.save();
          console.log("default admin successfully added.");
        } catch (error: any) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

I wanted to know how I can do this in NestJS?
Does NestJS or typeOrm have a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use [lifecycle events](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lifecycle-events#lifecycle-events-1). NestJS fires events during application bootstrapping and shutdown.

According to doc, `onApplicationBootstrap()` event may be helpful in your case.

> Called once all modules have been initialized, but before listening for connections.

However, NestJS does not expose a hook after the application starts listening, so in this case you need to run your custom function inside of `bootstrap` function right after the server could listen to a port.

The pseudocode would be like this:

```ts
// main.ts
import { User } from '/path/to/user.entity';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  ...
  await app.listen(3000);
  let user = app.get(getRepositoryToken(User)); // You need to pass the entity file to typeorm
  await addDefaultAdmin(user); // Pass the user model, and call the function
}

bootstrap();
```

Comment: thank you. I fixed this with the **onApplicationBootstrap** lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 0):

You can implements OnApplicationBootstrap in your services like this:

[image]

You can use onModuleInit in some case too.

This part of Nestjs [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lifecycle-events#usage) can help!